# Loading resources with rigged laravel?

Tags: .htaccess, laravel-4

So, I'm on a shared hosting account which means my root is my public_html folder. In order to get Laravel to work according to my knowledge is to throw the core files above public_html.
I managed to get it working with the following htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1 [L]
```

That worked fine until I tried to load my css files.

When I try to load the css with what I assume will work ( site.com/css/style.css ) It throws a 404 and cannot be accessed. Below is the /public folder layout.
/public/ folder layout:

[image: /public folder layout]

If anyone has any ideas, I'd be glad to hear them. I'm quite sorry if this is a simple fix or if this was already posted, I wasn't given any good recommendations while creating this.

Comment: Why not just rename public to public_html, and use that as your web root? You just need to change the path in `bootstrap/paths.php`.

Comment: I've tried what you said and it doesn't seem to make a difference, I can't access my css files located in /public/ still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should *never* be throwing the core files above `public_html`.

Just leave the `.htaccess` file untouched - and rename the folder `public` to `public_html`. Then inside `bootstrap/paths.php` change

```
'public' => __DIR__.'/../public',
```

to

```
'public' => __DIR__.'/../public_html',
```

You'll also need to run `composer update` after the change.

Comment: Hi. I don't have access to anything above public_html, nor do I have access to ssh for composer (it's not installed.) Should it work either way? Or what.

Comment: Are you sure? Most hosts give you one folder above `public_html`. If not -I'd just get a new host

Comment: I'm on a shared hosting account and don't receive access to anything above it.

Comment: Then just get a new host. They are cheap - there is really no reason not to. You can use Laravel Forge to be up and running in like 5mins